# How to encrypt and decrypt the string using 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I actually manage to encrypt and decrypt the plain string using 2d array.

Below is my encrypt code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Secret {

    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence that need to be encrypt : ");
        String y = x.nextLine();
    
        int len = y.length();
        
        System.out.println("The length of the sentences is : " + len);
        
        System.out.print("Enter number of column : " );
        int arr = x.nextInt();  
        
        char [] [] z = new char [6] [arr];
        
        // fill the character into array //
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<z.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<z[i].length; j++) {
                z[i][j] = y.charAt(pos);
                pos++;
        
                    }
            }
             // output the encrypted text by reading the array downward, column by
column.//
              for (int j = 0; j<z[arr].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(z[0][j] + "" + z[1][j] + "" + z[2][j] + "" + z[3][j] + "" + z[4][j] 
            + "" + z[5][j]);}   
            }
    }
```

Input:

```
Enter a sentence that need to be encrypt : 
Hello World.
The length of the sentences is : 12
Enter number of column : 2
```

Output:

```
HloWrdel ol.
```

But my desired output is something like this `HloWrdel*ol...` which means that the space is replace by `"*"` and if have extra empty array print `"."` instead.

Right now, my array size is depend on string length so when I input arr = 3 ( 6 X 3 = 18 ) it show the error like this

```
Enter a sentence that need to be encrypt : 
Hello World.
The length of the sentences is : 12
Enter number of column : 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:711)
    at Secret.main(Secret.java:33)
```

Therefore, my question is how to come out the desired output like this `HloWrdel*ol...`? The space becomes `"*"` and there is no limit for entering the array size. When I enter the array size (column) that is more than the string length, the character of the string automatically fill up the array and the extra empty array will print `"."` instead.

For decryption code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Secret1 {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the sentences that need to decrypt : ");
        String str = x.nextLine();
        
        int len = str.length();
        
        System.out.println("The number of length is " + len);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows : " );
        int arr = x.nextInt();
        
        char [][] z = new char [arr][6];
        
        // fill character into array //
        int pos = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<z.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<z[i].length; j++) {
                z[i][j] = str.charAt(pos);
                pos++ ;
        }
        
        }
        
        //output the decrypted text by reading the array from left to right, row by
row.//
        for (int i = 0; i<z.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(z[i][0]);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i<z.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(z[i][1]);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i<z.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(z[i][2]);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i<z.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(z[i][3]);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i<z.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(z[i][4]);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i<z.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(z[i][5]);
        }
            }
            
            }
```

Input:

```
Enter the sentences that need to decrypt : 
HloWrdel ol.
The number of length is 12
Enter the number of rows : 
2
```

Output:

```
Hello World.
```

But my desired output is from encrypted text `HloWrdel*ol...` into plain text `Hello World.`. How can I get such output?

Besides, the decryption code is also depend on string length so when I enter the array size more than string length, it show like this:

```
Enter the sentences that need to decrypt : 
HloWrdel ol.
The number of length is 12
Enter the number of rows : 
3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:711)
    at Secret1.main(Secret1.java:147)
```

Is it possible the array size that I have enter is not limited to the string length but print nothing for the extra empty array after filling into the array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inside your innermost loop (the `for (int j = 0; j<z[i].length; j++)`), check if `pos >= len`, and if so, skip attempting to read and fill the 2D element with '.'

```
if (pos>=len)
{
    z[i][j]='.';
    continue;
}

//your normal code
```

And then after you fill the element, check if you've just filled it with space

```
if (z[i][j]==' ')
    z[i][j]='*';
```